# What's the practical difference between @RequestParam and @RequestPart for multipart file in spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartfile

The [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html) states
**@RequestParam** relies on type conversion via a registered Converter or PropertyEditor while **@RequestPart** relies on HttpMessageConverters taking into consideration the 'Content-Type' header of the request part

1. Now, what would be the practical differences between the two, in case all configurations are left to default
2. What difference does it make, in case I upload a JSON/XML file and use @RequestParam or   @RequestPart?